# Select time range from unix-timestamp

Tags: mysql, date, timestamp, range, timespan

I have a MYSQL table with two columns, timestamp and span. timestamp is a unix-timestamp, while span is an integer.

I want to select all rows where the timestamp is between the current time +- half the span.

Eg. if the current time is 23:00, then I want all rows where the timestamp time is between 21 and 01. The issue is of-course that all the timestamps are from different days.

**TO CLARIFY, I don't care about the date only the time**

I've figured out a way to do this, but it seems like such a hack. I'm sure that someone with more MYSQL knowledge could show me a prettier way to do this.

```
SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE (
        TIME( DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL( span /2 ) HOUR ) ) <= TIME( DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL( span /2 ) HOUR ) )
        AND (
            TIME( FROM_UNIXTIME( timestamp ) ) >= TIME( DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL( span /2 ) HOUR ) )
            AND TIME( FROM_UNIXTIME( timestamp ) ) <= TIME( DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL( span /2 ) HOUR ) )
            )
        )
    OR (
        TIME( DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL( span /2 ) HOUR ) ) >= TIME( DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL( span /2 ) HOUR ) )
        AND (
            TIME( FROM_UNIXTIME( timestamp ) ) >= TIME( DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL( span /2 ) HOUR ) )
            OR TIME( FROM_UNIXTIME( timestamp ) ) <= TIME( DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL( span /2 ) HOUR ) )
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't really find a pretty solution, but this is how i ended up doing it.

```
SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE date_add( from_unixtime( timestamp ) , INTERVAL datediff( now( ) , from_unixtime( timestamp ) ) DAY )
    BETWEEN date_sub( now( ) , INTERVAL (span/2) HOUR )
    AND date_add( now( ) , INTERVAL (span/2) HOUR )
    OR date_add( from_unixtime( timestamp ) , INTERVAL datediff( now( ) , from_unixtime( timestamp ) ) -1 DAY )
    BETWEEN date_sub( now( ) , INTERVAL (span/2) HOUR )
    AND date_add( now( ) , INTERVAL (span/2) HOUR )
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options I recommend.

1. Benchmark your "hack" query and see if that is faster than running two MySQL queries.  Eg: One query to get your target row, another query to get results with ±1/2 span.
2. Write a proper MySQL stored procedure.  This is effectively option (1) but all done inside the DB.

Another option I don't recommend, based on past pain, is to use MySQL variables to effectively do two selects avoiding the stored procedure, eg: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html.  This approach was common back in the old days of PHP/MySQL apps.

In my experience odds are good option (1) is both fast enough and readable.